# Adding Clang to a docker container with mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk as its base

Tags: asp.net, docker, .net-core, clang

I have a dockerised asp.net project which is suppose to execute a script which complies some C code using clang. Is there a way to add the clang complier into this docker image. My dockerfile currently looks like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /build

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x |  bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN apt-get install build-essential -y

RUN apt-get install -y clang

COPY ./*.csproj .
RUN dotnet restore

COPY . .
WORKDIR /build
RUN dotnet publish -c release -o published --no-cache

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /build/published ./
ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet", "my_project.dll" ]
```

Comment: You have a `RUN apt-get install -y clang`. Does that not work? Have you tried a specific version such as `RUN apt-get install -y clang-12`?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to install clang is to download the pre-built clang binaries from https://releases.llvm.org/download.html, extract it and add it to the PATH. You'll see that clang 10 has available binaries for Ubuntu 18.04, clang 11 for 20.04.
The docker tag you are using (v3.1) is based on Debian 10 (see https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-sdk). Since they already provide tags w/ and Ubuntu base image, its probably best to switch to one of them (3.1-focal) when using the pre-built binaries (though, the Ubuntu 18.04 binaries should work on Debian 10)